# Заходить или зайти?

Tags: грамматика

Что лучше: Ты можешь ли *заходить* ко мне или *зайти*?

Comment: Either way, drop the **ли**. It's too bookish

Answer (score 7):

Заходить - если несколько раз, или регулярно.

Зайти - если один раз, например, через пять минут.

Answer (score 1):

В данном случае лучше без частицы **`ли`**

А что касается того, что уместней, то без обстоятельства уместней **`зайти`**

**`заходить`** требует уточнения обстоятельством, например:

`Ты можешь ко мне заходить` **`каждый вечер`** `?`
`Ты можешь ко мне заходить` **`раз в неделю`** `?`
`Ты можешь ко мне заходить` **`почаще/иногда`** `?`

Answer (score 0):

"Ты можешь ли зайти ко мне?" sounds odd and artificial. It'd be better to say: "Не можешь ли ты зайти ко мне?" or "Mожешь ли ты зайти ко мне?" or "Ты можешь зайти ко мне?" or "Mожешь зайти ко мне?" or "Ко мне зайти можешь?"
When you say:"Ты можешь ли заходить ко мне?", you sound old-fashioned, stilted, reproachful and demanding as if you were a nobleman and some of your servants dared to enter your private room. Something like: "How can it be possible that you, servant, make an entry in my chamber?"